# Rails Upgrade 4.2 -> 5 - Bundler not able to resolve exact gem version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile, rails-upgrade

I'm getting this error in upgrading various gems, as I'm trying to move from 4.2.11.1 to 5.0.1. Sample error for actionpack:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.1)

    simple_form (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0)

    twitter-bootstrap-rails (= 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (~> 5.0, >= 5.0.1)
```

As far as my understanding is concerned about gem versions, this should not be an error, as version 5.0.1 satisfies all the dependencies. Can someone explain how can I get rid of such errors? I'm getting many such errors while upgrading

Comment: delete your gemfile.lock and try 'bundle update'

Comment: That runs for 6-7 hours and nothing happens. @honey. It is just stuck at "Resolving dependencies" step.

Comment: have you tried with mentioning specific version for the gem ?

Answer (score -2):

This is a tedious task and won't always be as easy.

I would suggest you follow this approach:

1. Try deleting the `Gemfile.lock` also try to remove the gem versions from `Gemfile` if possible unless you specifically need the version. (you might want to keep version of `rails`, `devise`, `aasm` locked as there might be some major changes)
2. Run `bundle install`
3. At this step there are still chances you might get some conflicts in versions and dependencies
4. You will have to open and check the specific gems for the dependencies

Comment: This is not working for me. Whenever I do this and run bundler, it gets stuck completely on "Resolving dependencies" step. I waited for more than 5-6 hours before killing that task. @Deepak

Comment: Well in that case you might have to upgrade failing gems one by one. In your case try `bundle update actionpack` 
You will have to do this for lot of gems and it will indeed take few hours depending on the size of the `Gemfile`

Comment: Easy approach. Comment gems from gemfile and try to run `bundle` with 10 gems then uncomment 10 more maybe

Comment: I understand your binary search kind of approach. Just wanted to learn - Is this even a valid error or is there some issue in my understanding of how bundler resolves things?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid error when "few of your gem requires the older version but other gem requires a newer version and they don't overlap "

To give you an example one requires `<= 5` but the other require `> 6` of the same gem as dependency

Comment: can you check carefully? The above error doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It should use 5.0.1 IMO.